# Reading Other Addresses - ICO

Tags: ico

Suppose we have an address, call it "Receiver", which receives a certain amount of Ether from various investors. We also have a second wallet, call it "Sender", which is holding all of our newly created tokens.

Now the ICO finishes, and we want to issue the correct amount of tokens to each investor.

The question is, how can we create a "Sender" so that it can scan through "Receiver", calculate the corresponding tokens, and then send them to each investor?

Comment: What don't you make a smart contract?

Comment: Only "Sender" can use Smart Contracts. "Receiver" should be a simple address; without you having any access to it (unknown private key).

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are trying to do. For an ICO, just make a smart contract that give tokens every time it receives ether.

Comment: I do understand how to make a standard ICO. My question is, would this type of ICO be possible? Sorry if I did not make this clear, this is just a theoretical question.

Comment: If receiver is JUST an address (normal "account"), then you have no way to check, only using the blockchain (uncless you go through all transactions receipts), who sent what, and then no way to send tokens to their theoratical owners.

Comment: I mean, this information is stored in the blockchain; just like a balance is. How is it that we can access the balance of an address, but not its transactions? How is it then that Etherscan.io is able to find and display all transactions linked with an address through smart contracts? Just asking.

Comment: I'm still confused with what you are trying to do. From what I understood, what you think about is so much complicated when a few lines of code can do that. Sorry if I am not helpful, but I don't really understand the point of this :S

Comment: There is literally no point. I was just trying to know if it was possible to retrieve incoming transactions information from any address. No worries, all ideas are helpful :)

Comment: Ah, for this, yes you can. The only way (for now and according to my knowledge) is to scna the entire blockchain (or a range of blocks) and check all their transaction where the "to" property is your receiver address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* you would want to do this but anyways. Lets say you start your ICO at block 4,900,900 and continue until block 4,900,999. After you conclude the ICO, you could run a python script that searches the transaction history in between those blocks, calculating the total amount of ether sent from each address. Afterwards, you can have the same python script calculate how many tokens each person is to receive, and then utilizing web3py (or another web3 library) you can contact your token contract, and tell it to send X coin to Y address.

That being said I have no idea why you wouldn't just write a smart contract to do an ICO. Not only would it probably require significantly LESS development time, testing, and lines of code but it would all be handled autonomously via on-chain processes through the use of smart contracts.

Also I would **never invest in an ICO where the recipient address is a plain old address and not a contract** as it would look like a scam just an FYI. I imagine many other people will feel the same way.

And yes its entirely possible to tell an address, from a contract address. You could use the assembly opcode `extcodesize(addr)` amongst other tactics.

edit:

I can't remember the name but there was an ICO that scammed it's investors and the recipient address was a plane old address not a contract address.